# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField and CheckboxSelectMultiple - display extra data from queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible to access additional data apart from key, value pairs in django forms ModelMultipleChoiceField?

My goal is to generate an input (checkbox) with its name (value) and extra information like price, additional description and possibly other data.

I use django-crispy-forms and I would love to keep it within it by creating a template for example.

**Edit**

I was thinking of having something like

```
<input value="{{ object.id }}"> 
{{object.name}} - {{object.description}} {{object.price}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way its a method called `label_from_instance` which accept `obj` as arguments and return the `obj` representation.

You can either Inherit from ModelMultipleChoiceField and override it, or dynamically change it during form creation. Here are some examples:

#### Inheritance

```
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField

class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id

#and then you have to use it in your form:
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_multi_choice_field = MyModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=...)
```

#### or by overriding

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_multi_choice_field'].label_from_instance = self.label_from_instance
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit? I'm looking for something more advanced which would let me to generate a table for example. I'm not sure if label_from_instance would be enough for it.

Comment: The default widget for `ModelMultipleChoiceField` is `SelectMultiple` which is `<select multiple='multiple'><option ...>...</select>`. The `label_from_instance` method allows you to override what gets inside the `<option></option>` tag. If that's not enough then you will need a custom widget. (I still don't get what you mean by generating a table...).