# How to override ModelChoiceField / ModelMultipleChoiceField default widget with a template for each choice

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

### Background

I have two models, Runs and Orders. One run will complete many orders, so I have a Many-to-one relation between my orders and runs, represented as a foreignkey on my orders.

I want to build a UI to create a run. It should be a form in which someone selects orders to run. I'd like to display a list of checkboxes alongside information about each order. I'm using [django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) right now.

**views.py**

```
class createRunView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Run
    form_class = CreateRunForm
    template_name = 'runs/create_run.html'
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateRunForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Run
       fields = ['orders',]

    orders = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Order.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_loaded=False))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('orders', template="runs/list_orders.html"),
            Submit('save', 'Create Run'),
            Button('cancel', 'Cancel'),
    )
```

---

### Questions

1. I'm not sure what locals are available to me in the `list_orders.html` template. It seems like there's `{{ field }}` and maybe `form.visible_fields` but if I dig to deeply into either I get a `TypeError: 'SubWidget' object is not iterable`, which is barely documented online.
2. The above suggests I might still be getting a widget in the template, despite the fact that `Field('orders', template="runs/list_orders.html"),` should prevent that, per the [crispy docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html):

   > **Field**: Extremely useful layout object. You can use it to set attributes in a field or render a specific field with a custom template. This way you avoid having to explicitly override the field’s widget and pass an ugly attrs dictionary:
3. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858503/django-modelmultiplechoicefield-and-checkboxselectmultiple-display-extra-data) which suggests using `label_from_instance`. However I'm not sure how to stuff a bunch of html into `label_from_instance`. Instead of having a different label, I really want to have a template which generates a bunch of html which shows details about the entire order object, so I'm not sure this approach will work.
4. The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300685/how-to-get-modelchoicefield-instances-in-the-template) mostly confused me, but the accepted answer didn't work, it seems. (maybe a django version issue, or a crispy forms issue?)

### TL;DR

How do I render templates with data from each model in ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Comment: Have you tried to use a custom widget @AlexLenail? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675550/django-widget-override-template/44678736#44678736

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Widgets control how fields are rendered in HTML forms. The Select widget (and its variants) have two attributes `template_name` and `option_template_name`. The `option_template_name` supplies the name of a template to use for the select options. You can subclass a select widget to override these attributes. Using a subclass, like [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple), is probably a good place to start because by default it will not render options in a `<select>` element, so your styling will be easier.

By default the CheckboxSelectMultiple `option_template_name` is [`'django/forms/widgets/checkbox_option.html'`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/checkbox_option.html).

You can supply your own template that will render the details of the orders how you want. IE in your `forms.py`

```
class MyCheckboxSelectMultiple(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    option_template_name = 'myapp/detail_options.html'

class CreateRunForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    orders = ModelMultipleChoiceField(..., widget=MyCheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Suppose that `myapp/detail_options.html` contained the following

```
{# include the default behavior #}
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input_option.html" %} 
{# add your own additional div for each option #}
<div style="background-color: blue">
    <h2>Additional info</h2>
</div>
```

You would see that blue div after each label/input. Something like this

[image: Custom option template]

Now, the trick will be how you get the object available to the widget namespace. By default, only certain attributes are present on a widget, as returned by the widget's [`get_context` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.get_context).

You can use your own subclass of `MultipleModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance` to accomplish this. The value returned by `label_from_instance` is ultimately made available to the widgets as the `label` attribute, which is used for the visible text in your model form, when it renders `{{ widget.label }}`.

Simply override `label_from_instance` to return the entire object then use this subclass for your field.

```
class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj

class CreateRunForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    orders = MyModelMultipleChoiceField(..., widget=MyCheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

So now in the `myapp/detail_options` template you can use `widget.label` to access the object directly and format your own content as you please. For example, the following option template could be used

```
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input_option.html" %}
{% with order=widget.label %}
    <div style="background-color: blue">
        <h2>Order info</h2>
        <p style="color: red">Order Active: {{ order.is_active }}</p>
        <p style="color: red">Order Loaded: {{ order.is_loaded }}</p>
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

And it would produce the following effect.

[image: object hack]

This also will not disrupt the default behavior of the widget label text wherever `widget.label` is used. Note that in the above image the label texts (e.g. `Order object (1)`) are the same as before we applied the change to `label_from_instance`. This is because the default in template rendering is to use `str(obj)` when presented with a model object; the same thing that would have previously been done by the default `label_from_instance`.

## TL;DR

- Make your own subclasses of `ModelMultiplechoiceField` to have `label_from_instance` return the object.
- Make your own SelectMultiple widget subclass to specify a custom `option_template_name`.
- The template specified will be used to render each option, where `widget.label` will be each object.

Comment: I can't get the first part of this to work, unfortunately. I change `detail_options.html` but can't get what's in there to render. All that renders is the default ModelMultipleChoiceField widget. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to debug this, since I've followed this answer exactly, and can't even get an error to lead me somewhere. Maybe this has to do with django-crispy-forms?

Comment: what should the root of the path for `option_template_name` be? I tried `/myapp/templates/orders/detail_options.html` as well as just `/orders/detail_options.html` and neither worked. Is there some way I can _force_ the app to break somehow which would tell me why it seems to be ignoring these changes?

Comment: To make this solution work, I did :
1. Add 'django.forms' to INSTALLED_APPS.
2. Add FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting' to settings.py.
as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69955313/15060764)